# Cookie - PHP registration

Tags: php, cookie

Все привет, я сделал регистрацию на страничке, код:

```
<?php 
                if($_COOKIE['user'] == ''):
            ?>

                <form action="check.php" method="post">
                    <element class="plabel">
                        <p>Rejestracja</p>
                    <p class="plabell">
                    <p class="plabell">Imie: <p><input type="text" name="name" class="buttonmoon"></p></p>
                    <p class="plabell">Login: <p><input type="text" name="login" class="buttonmoon"></p></p>
                    <p class="plabell">Haslo: <p><input type="password" name="password" class="buttonmoon"></p></p>
                    </p>
                    <p class="plabell"><p><input type="submit" value="Zarejestruj" class="buttonmoon"></p></p>
                    </element>
                </form>
                <br><br><br>
                <form action="auth.php" method="post">
                    <element class="plabel">
                        <p>Zaloguj się</p>
                    <p class="plabell">
                    <p class="plabell">Login: <p><input type="text" name="login" class="buttonmoon"></p></p>
                    <p class="plabell">Haslo: <p><input type="password" name="password" class="buttonmoon"></p></p>
                    </p>
                    <p class="plabell"><p><input type="submit" value="Zaloguj" class="buttonmoon"></p></p>
                    </element>
                </form>
                
                <?php else:?>
                    <p>Hello, <?=$_COOKIE['user']?>. If you want to exit - press <a
                    href="exit.php">here</a><p>
                <?php endif;?>
```

И когда я в окне регистрации то у меня еще нету COOKIE и это логично, и у меня пишет
**Warning: Undefined array key "user" in...**
то есть я понимаю что его нету еще, но можно как то это не показывать?

Comment: `if !isset.....`

Comment: Исправил, спасибо!